# Seperate data into set in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
let data = [];

 $(".clo :input").each(function(index,value){   
      data[this.id] = $(this).val();
 });

 console.log(data); //display data below
[
  agent_dra_0: "0"
  agent_tie_0: "0"
  agent_tiger_0: "0"
  agent_userid_0: "2"
  agent_dra_1: "0"
  agent_tie_1: "k"
  agent_tiger_1: "1"
  agent_userid_1: "4"
]
```

Above data I loop all the input value into one array, I want to separate those data into set data. Which means that every index store into one array. It will become as below. Anyone know how to fix this :(.

```
0: [{
  agent_dra_0: "0",
  agent_tie_0: "0",
  agent_tiger_0: "0",
  agent_userid_0: "2"
}

1: {
  agent_dra_1: "0",
  agent_tie_1: "0",
  agent_tiger_1: "0",
  agent_userid_1: "4"
}]
```

Comment: Do you need to create the array first and *then* separate it?  It would be easier to create the final output directly within your `.each` loop

Comment: @freedomn-m , ya need to create in new variable. Because I want separate and store in new array. Hence, the data will have more in the future. So need to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must build an array of objects and then use array reduce to group by numbers.

```js
// Try edit message

let x = [
  {agent_dra_0: "0"},
  {agent_tie_0: "0"},
  {agent_tiger_0: "0"},
  {agent_userid_0: "2"},
  {agent_dra_1: "0"},
  {agent_tie_1: "k"},
  {agent_tiger_1: "1"},
  {agent_userid_1: "4"},
];

let xx = x.reduce((xx, item)=>{
  let key = Object.keys(item)[0].split('_').pop();

  xx[key] = (xx[key]) ? xx[key]:[];
  var a = Object.keys(item)[0];
  var b = {};
  b[a] = item[a];
  xx[key].push(b);
  return xx;
},{});
console.log(xx);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the feature that `x.a = 1` is the same as `x["a"] = 1` to generate your new item property values along with the `for (var key in object)` to get the named array entries from your source data.

- Loop through each item
- extract the index from the property name (in this case I've use `.lastIndexOf`, but `.split` would work just as well, or a regex if it's more complicated than the example provided)
- ensure that entry in the result exists as a sub-array `result[idx] = result[idx] || []`
- create a new object to put in the sub-array
- use `x["a"]=value` to add named properties to the new object
- add to the sub-array

```js
var data = [];
$(":input").each(function(index, value) {
  data[this.id] = $(this).val();
});
var result = [];
for (var key in data) {
  var idx = key.substr(key.lastIndexOf('_') + 1)
  result[idx] = result[idx] || [];
  var entry = {};
  entry[key] = data[key];
  result[idx].push(entry);
}
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="agent_dra_0" value="1">
<input id="agent_tie_0" value="2">
<input id="agent_dra_1" value="3">
<input id="agent_tie_1" value="4">
```